# Storing the output json parameters as variable in jmeter using it in next request

Tags: jmeter, json-extract

I have a http request which gives json output as :

```
{
"MESSAGE_CODE":200,
"MESSAGE_DESCRIPTION":"OTP Generated Successfully",
"data":
{
"otp":"123456",
"otpGeneratedDate":"yyyy-mm-dd"
}
}
```

I want to use otp as the input parameter in json for my next http request.

I  have added JSON extractor with following configuration :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZeOU.png)

Names of created variable : OTP
JSON path expressions : $..data.otp
Match No. : 1

But still when I am calling this parameter as

"otpNumber": "${OTP}" in my next input JSON http request, its not getting called.
and value is passed as ${OTP} for otpNumber

How can I handle this

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Variables, functions (and properties) **are all case-sensitive**

So you need to change this line:

```
"otpNumber": "${OTP}"
```

to this one:

```
"otpNumber": "${otp}"
```

and your test should start working as expected.

You can observe which JMeter Variables are defined along with their values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script).

[image]

Comment: Tried that also.

Issue here is that I am trying to use that variable in another thread.
Is it possible?

Comment: You cannot use JMeter Variables defined in one Thread Group in another Thread Group. You will either need to convert it into a JMeter Property using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) in one Thread Group and refer it using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in another one or go for [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter)